# Applied for a UK standard visitor visa as a couple but didn't receive any confirmation email from UKVI

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

I and my husband have applied for standard UK visitor visa from Pakistan. But we didn't receive any confirmation email from UKVI upon submitting our bio metrics as last time I received the mail from UKVI Abu dhabi. Should I be worried?

Comment: How long have you waited? Did you try contacting them?